Price OIS fairRate and PV01 without creating OvernightIndexedSwap object?
With QuantLib Python, I'm able to build OIS curve and reprice the inputs by using OvernightIndexedSwap with schedule. Would like to know is there a way to price PV01 and fairRate() of OIS/IRS without creating OvernightIndexedSwap object with schedule please?

There might be approximate ways but they might be more complicated than using the existing objects. What is the problem in using a schedule?

Thanks Luigi. It is taking about 18 seconds to price 720 OIS but I was trying to price them within 1 second hence the question.

Calculating the rate and PV from the curve may be complicated, and it would be approximated anyway if you don't consider all the conventions in OvernightIndexedSwap.
If the problem is the performance, it might be because by default the OIS is calculating each daily fixing and compounding it.  It's possible to tell it to use a telescopic rule to estimate future coupons, which makes it faster; to enable this, pass True as the value of the telescopicValueDates parameter in the OvernightIndexedSwap constructor you're using; see here for their declaration.  Unfortunately, overloaded constructors means that it's not possible to use keyword arguments in Python for this class, so you'll have to also pass all the parameters before telescopicValueDates.
Note that the telescopic rule cannot be used in all cases, depending on the fixing days of the underlying index, the lookback days of the swap, and whether there's an observation shift; the implementation of the check is here.  The swap will raise an exception if you pass telescopicValueDates = True and the rule can't be applied.
